# Jmeter distributed testing

Tags: testing, jmeter

I'm using JMeter distributed testing for load testing. The problem is the client gets stopped immediately after starting it. Don't know why.

Can anybody help me in this problem?

Comment: Mention the steps you have done so far. Otherwise, it's impossible to Pinpoint the root cause of your problem.

Comment: 1) Started jmeter in one system (both jmeter.bat and jmeter-server.bat) and made that system as server                                                                                                                                    2) Then started jmeter in another system (both jmeter.bat and jmeter-server.bat)   and made that system as client                                                     3) updated the remote host ip in the properties file in server system with the ip of the client system                                                                  4)Then started the remote client

Comment: check whether the PORTs you are using for the both the Master and slaves are not blocked.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow these steps:

1. Start **only jmeter-server.bat** from the slave machines. (no need to run both jmeter.bat and jmeter-server.bat)
2. Configure **jmeter.properties** file of the master machine as follows:

> Remote Hosts - comma delimited
>
> remote_hosts=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (IP of your slave machines)

3. Start **jmeter.bat** from client(master) machine.
4. Now you can run your test from GUI mode to check everything is okay or not.

To do this: **Run->Remote start-> check the IP's of slaves. (if its in there you are ready to run your test remotely).**

**Pre-requisites:**

1. All the machines (both master and slaves) must be in the **same subnet**.
2. **Firewall** must be turned off for all machines.
3. **Java and JMeter versions** must be same for all machines.

For more details, you should read [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf).

Comment: i have done the above steps. then in the console in slave machine:   Could  not find ApacheJmeter_core.jar...                                                                   ... Trying JMETER_HOME=..                                                                           Found ApacheJmeter_core.jar                                                                       Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.0.42:51311](local),objID:[-4abc6985:154eba06cfc:-7fff, -4399530876420941613]]]

Comment: Starting the test on host 192.168.0.142 @ Thu May 26 11:24:29 IST 2016 (1464242069401)                                                                                                 Finished the test on host 192.168.0.142 @ Thu May 26 11:24:45  IST 2016 (1464242085627)

Comment: Yeah, it is okay. This should be in the console of the slave machine. So, what's the problem here? Did you check your report from the client machine (GUI mode)? and please mention your test duration here. Is it less than 16 seconds?

Comment: i'm not getting any report from the client machine (GUI mode). Actually the test is not running... the slave machine gets stopped immediately after starting it.. This is the problem...

Comment: what is shown in your jmeter.log? Did you follow all the pre-requisites for remote testing??

Comment: jmeter.log                                                                                                                  2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 192.168.0.142 
2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting remote engines 
2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting the test @ Thu May 26 12:08:38 IST 2016 (1464244718566) 
2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method

Comment: 2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000

Comment: 2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to 192.168.0.142 basedir='.' 
2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Sending properties {} 
2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to 192.168.0.142 
2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started

Comment: 2016/05/26 12:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,192.168.0.142) 
2016/05/26 12:08:54 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,192.168.0.142)