# Jmeter non http code error (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponse Exception)

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I generated .jtl from JMeter and created auto generated report from [blaze meter](https://sense.blazemeter.com) and it was working fine with `HTTP status code 200`.

Now I am trying same with non-GUI mode and doing remote testing, trying to create test report from online blaze meter but I am getting non-HTTP response code from auto generated report of blaze meter while getting 200 on JMeter.

Error is `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponse Exception`

Comment: Hope this will help: [Why Are My HTTP 200 OK Counted As Errors](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421105-Why-are-my-HTTP-200-OK-counted-as-errors-)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when a sample returns a `200 OK` and failed status, it means **a failed embedded resource sample or a failed assertion**.

On your sampler dashboard did you tick the checkbox that states: `Retrieve Embedded Resources`? If so, you do use embedded resources. When you enable the `View Results in Tree` listener, you should see the top-level **sample/response**, **sub-samples**. One of them should be red (while the others are green).

For details, you could see [this](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421105-Why-are-my-HTTP-200-OK-counted-as-errors-).

Comment: I have already added a listener View Results in Tree and all http status codes are green with 200 and I have not added any assertion. As I am new to jmeter can you please tell me what is Retrieve Embedded Resources and what is sampler dashboard? Thanks.

Comment: You will find "Retrieve Embedded Resources" checkbox at the bottom of your HTTP Request tab (Http sampler dashboard). This checkbox is used to  simulate a browser retrieving embedded resources (such as gifs, css, js etc).

Comment: So I think, you don't see any sub-samples because you haven't checked the "Retrieve Embedded Resources" option. This is used to make JMeter behaviour more like a real browser.

Comment: Nothing happened. May be I have not configured remote setting correctly. 
I tried jmeter gui after remote configuration  to start test but gui was freezed and after some time it throws error engine is busy so tried this from non-gui mode right now from gui it is throwing this error java.rmi.connect exception connection refused to host. What should i do now? your help will highy appreciated.

Comment: You can follow these steps that I mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451710/jmeter-distributed-testing/37452156#37452156) for remote testing configuration.

Comment: I am following the same steps but still no success. Can you tell me how can I configure ports. Also adding the my master ip is 192.168.x.x and slave is 213.185.x.x. I am running my test on jmeter through this slave ip 213.185.x.x .This is Linux server and it is in cloud in some other country. Is this is a cause of problem?

Comment: All the machines (both master and slaves) must be in the same subnet. Your master seems local.

Comment: so you mean master cant be local? and I cannot do test in the scenario that I told you that my salve is in another country.

Comment: Did you read those Pre-requisites that I've mentioned on the link? you should read the apache documentation first to configure the remote testing environment. See here: [Remote testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Comment: Yes i am following everything from here but from non gui  and gui mode I am getting error "engine is busy"
no luck :(

Comment: What have you done so far? please describe the steps you followed. and also mention when are you getting this error?

Comment: Firstly client configration
remote_hosts=213.187.x.x, 
client.rmi.localport=7000

Server side:
client.rmi.localport=7000
server.rmi.localport=60000
then  on slave i am giving ./jemeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=213.187.x.x
it creates remote object and when i open jemter GUI on master and starts the test system gets stuck and after sometime Its says engine is busy

Comment: Also when i try ro create ssh tunnel to avoid same subnet and firewall thingy I am giving command ssh -R 7000:213.187.x.x:7000 USER@SERVER then system ask for password and when I provide password It says, Segmentation fault.